# How to bind macros to combination like letter+number, like X+1?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I bind macros to combinations like letter+number, like X+1, C+1, etc. in World of Warcraft?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. The only combinations you can create are with modifier keys like Control, Alt, and Shift.

There are two ways to go about this. Either create a simple macro and drag it to a slot on your action bar that's bound to the combination you want (like Ctrl-1), or modify the macro to do something different if a modifier key is pressed.

For example,`/cast [nomodifier] Chain Heal; [modifier:alt] Greater Healing Wave` will cast a Chain Heal if no modifier is pressed, and cast Greater Healing Wave when the macro is used while you press Alt.

Answer (score -3):

You could also do something like

```
#showtooltip 
/castsequence reset=target Victory Rush, Execute, Execute, Execute, Execute
```

But instead of victory rush or execute the skills that you want, the icon will change once you cast a skill and cast different skills with one press of a button.

Comment: While yes, that can be done, it is completely unrelated to the question as far as I can tell.